# Does Wilcoxon Signed Rank (paired test) in R automatically analyse data by row?

Tags: r, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have multiple rows of observation periods [OP] (of varying durations)  showing the average food intake rate of the first quarter of the OP compared to the last quarter of the OP. See the table below.

| OP | Intake.Q1 | Intake.Q4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | 6 |
| 2 | 19.5 | 5 |
| 3 | 5.1 | 2.5 |
| 4 | 4.7 | 2.1 |
| 5 | 10.6 | 5.4 |

I want to find out if there is a significant difference between the first and the last quarter of each OP.

If I run a Wilcoxon test in R:

wilcox.test(IntakeQ1, IntakeQ4, alternative=("two.sided"), paired=TRUE)

**My question is**: How will R analyse this data, because I need it to compare the time points in **each** OP then give me a final result of whether intake rate significantly changes during observation period.

So will it compare 6 & 6, then 19.5 & 5, then 5.1 and 2.5, etc. then give me a final output, or will it aggregate everything in Intake.Q1 and compare to everything in Intake.Q4?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since a X and Y are provided and `paired=TRUE` option is used.

From help:

> "If both x and y are given and paired is TRUE, a Wilcoxon signed rank
> test of the null that the distribution of of x - y (in the paired two
> sample case) is symmetric about mu is performed."

Comment: I'm sorry, just to clarify, it will analyse row by row?

Comment: Yes, it will pair the first x with the first y, the second x with the second y, etc...

Comment: Nice idea to quote R help. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Putting your data into R as vectors `q1` and `q4`:

```
q1 = c(6, 19.5, 5.1, 4.7, 10.6)
q4 = c(6,  5,   2.5, 2.1,  5.4)
```

Your paired Wilcoxon test gives the following results:

```
wilcox.test(q1, q4, pair=T)  # 2-sided is default

        Wilcoxon signed rank test with 
        continuity correction

data:  q1 and q4
V = 10, p-value = 0.1003
alternative hypothesis: 
 true location shift is not equal to 0

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(q1, q2, pair = T) :
  cannot compute exact p-value with zeroes
```

Now find the five paired differences.

```
d = q1 - q4;  d
[1]  0.0 14.5  2.6  2.6  5.2

wilcox.test(d)  # 2-sided test with 0 null is default

        Wilcoxon signed rank test 
        with continuity correction

data:  d
V = 10, p-value = 0.1003
alternative hypothesis: 
  true location is not equal to 0

Warning message:
In wilcox.test.default(d) : 
  cannot compute exact p-value with zeroes
```

The result is exactly the same as for the 'paired' test.
The paired test begins by finding the paired
differences and then doing the one-sample Wilcoxon signed-rank
test on the differences (instead of the two-sample Wilcoxon rank sum test on the two samples, as if indepencent).

*Notes:* (1) Additional evidence.

- Taken separately, there are no ties in your
  two columns of data. So you might have wondered about
  the Warning message for the 'paired' test.
- However, upon taking differences,
  you do have a a $0$ difference and a tie (at 2.6) for two out of the five differences.

(2) Neither the $0$ nor the tie is the reason one fails to get significant results
at the 5% level--for just the five subjects you list as examples.

The following simulation
repeatedly jitters the data very slightly to avoid $0$ and to break ties. None of the
jittered data give significant results at the 5% level:

```
pv = replicate(10^4, wilcox.test(
                   d+runif(5, -.001,.001))$p.val)
summary(pv)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
0.06250 0.06250 0.06250 0.09354 0.12500 0.12500
```

Also, with only five subjects the smallest possible P-value for a one-sided test is $1/32$ and the smallest for a 2-sided test is $1/16 =  0.0625,$ achieved as the `min` in the simulation.

(3) The data seem to be numerical (instead of merely ordinal). Even if we assume differences are normal (and with only $n=5$ of them, there's no use trying to test that), a paired t test comes nowhere near significance
at the 5% level, partly because of a large variance.

```
t.test(d)$p.val
[1] 0.1191081
```